# Angular: how can I make a class member private but accesible for the template?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the followign component

component ts:

```
export class calculator {
    public elements;
    public findAll() {
     // backend stuff for retrieving data and assigning it to elements
    }

    public delete(obj) {
     // backend stuff for deleting obj
    }

    public save(obj) {
     // backend stuff for saving obj
    }
}
```

the component template:

```
<div>
  <button (click)="findAll()">Start!</button>
  <div>
     <div *ngFor="let elem for elements">
       <span>{{elem.name}}</span>
       <button (click)="delete(elem)"></button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to only the save method be accesible from outside the class, is there a way to achieve this?

```
class anotherClass {
   this.calculator.save(formula); // can't access to findAll or delete
}
```

EDIT:
I've try with the protected accesor, but I get the error:

> 'findAll' is protected and only accessible within class 'calculator'
>   and its subclasses.

Comment: use protected private variable can't use in template. it will failed in aot build

Comment: Thats what protected does, if you need to access findAll from outside the class/sub classes then make it public

Comment: right, I'm getting this error because findAll is used in the template. I want that method to be accesible for the template, but private for the rest of the classes. It looks like the protected accesor makes it private for the template as well.

Comment: Ok, you can't do that

Answer (score 0):

No you can't  do that.Templates do not exist within component classes, but outside of them. So private members is not accessible for Template